# How to create a CGVector that "points" from one point (CGPoint) to another point

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, skspritenode, swift5

I want to use a CGVector for a `SKAction.move`, which moves one SKSpriteNode towards another SKSpriteNode.

I want to use this code:

```
let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width))), y: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.height))))
let object: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(color: NSColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
object.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
addChild(object)
object.run(SKAction.move(by: CGVector(), duration: 2.5)) // <- Vector from `object.position` to `point`
```

Comment: A vector with origin point A and target point B is defined as B - A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use vector math
so looking at your code you want to use something like this:

```
let P1 = point
let P2 = object.position
//Find offset
let offset = P1 - P2
//Set X and Y distance to move
let distX = CGFloat(offset.x)
let distY = CGFloat(offset.y)
//set vector
let vec = CGVector(dx: distX, dy: distY)
//Set action
object.run(SKAction.move(by: vec, duration: 2.4)
```

Let me know how you get on

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not help me. I want to move `object` with `SKAction.move(by: CGVector(), duration: 2.5)`.

Comment: Ahhh my mistake I’ve updated the answer take another look

Comment: Does `object` move further in this direction if I multiply `distX` and `distY` with any number, for example 10?

Comment: HI Jojo, yes it will!! and it will move less if you use a CGFloat like 0.2. Be careful though and don't get disheartened multiplying these values will not give obvious results. Why ?? because they are based on the offset..... The offset is the difference in X and Y co-ordinates between point 1 and point 2.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I got a "Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two 'CGPoint' operands" error and did 
        let distX = (P1.x - P2.x) * 0.25
        let distY = (P1.y - P2.y) * 0.75 instead of using the offset variable (you probably don't need the *0.25 and *0.75, I'm not moving very far)